# ReferenceError: self is not defined on setup Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

i try to setup firebase for using cloud messaging on Web **[Javascript]** but i got some error like this below :

```
I20210208-15:21:52.756(7)? Exception while invoking method '/microfis_loanRequest/update' ReferenceError: self is not defined
I20210208-15:21:52.758(7)?     at isSupported (/Users/rabbit/Desktop/microfis/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/dist/index.cjs.js:1711:9)
I20210208-15:21:52.758(7)?     at Component.factoryMethod [as instanceFactory] (/Users/rabbit/Desktop/microfis/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/dist/index.cjs.js:1694:10)
I20210208-15:21:52.758(7)?     at Provider.getOrInitializeService (/Users/rabbit/Desktop/microfis/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/index.cjs.js:222:39)
I20210208-15:21:52.759(7)?     at Provider.getImmediate (/Users/rabbit/Desktop/microfis/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/index.cjs.js:120:33)
I20210208-15:21:52.759(7)?     at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (/Users/rabbit/Desktop/microfis/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:230:49)
I20210208-15:21:52.760(7)?     at FirebaseAppImpl.firebaseAppImpl.(anonymous function) [as messaging] (/Users/rabbit/Desktop/microfis/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:449:39)
I20210208-15:21:52.761(7)?     at Object.serviceNamespace [as messaging] (/Users/rabbit/Desktop/microfis/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:429:45)
I20210208-15:21:52.761(7)?     at Object.<anonymous> (microfis/server/collection_hooks/mobile-app-hook/loan-request.js:53:30)
I20210208-15:21:52.762(7)?     at packages/matb33_collection-hooks.js:486:20
I20210208-15:21:52.762(7)?     at Array.forEach (native)
```

here what i did for setup

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "API_KEY",
    authDomain: "AUTH_DOMAIN.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
    storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "SENDER_ID",
    appId: "APP_ID",
    measurementId: "MEASUREMENT_ID"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

here i try to use it :

```
    messaging.getToken({ vapidKey: 'VAPID_KEY' }).then((currentToken) => {
        if (currentToken) {
            // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
            // ...
            print(currentToken);
        } else {
            // Show permission request UI
            console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
            // ...
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
        // ...
    });
```

have any idea about this error , thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the Firebase SDK scripts and initialize in `index.html`. Instructions [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/web).

Comment: your link redirects to 404